# Definición de cols y rows de textarea

Tags: html

Yo sé que es una pregunta muy tonta pero no encontré una respuesta clara de lo que significaba *cols* y *rows* en un `textarea` para modificar el tamaño.

Comment: cols = columnas, es decir el ancho del text area, rows = filas, es decir el alto del mismo, es eso lo que preguntas?

Comment: ahh si muchas gracias escribelo en responder pregunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cols` se refiere al número de columnas que contendrá tu textarea, es decir el ancho que este tendrá a la hora de mostrarse en la página.

`rows` se refiere al número de filas que tendrá tu textarea, o en otras palabras la altura de el mismo.

Answer (score 1):

En un elemento `<textarea>`:

- El atributo `cols` (columnas) especifica el **ancho** visible del elemento, en anchos de carácter promedio
- El atributo `rows` (filas) especifica el **alto** visible del elemento, en líneas de texto

#### Véase también

- [HTML `<textarea>` cols Attribute (Documentación de W3Schools)](https://www.w3schools.com/TagS/att_textarea_cols.asp) (en inglés)
- [HTML `<textarea>` rows Attribute (Documentación de W3Schools)](https://www.w3schools.com/TagS/att_textarea_rows.asp) (en inglés)